# What number should replace the question mark in the grid below?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, progressive-matrix

I found this puzzle in a Finnish magazine. I can't seem to figure it out.

[image: From left to right, then top to bottom: 2, 6, 8; 3, 7, 3; 6, 4, ?]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> 1

because

> 268+373=641

Comment: Now I've seen everything. A "complete the pattern, but think outside the box" puzzle with a satisfying solution. Well done. :-)